# Backend column sorting does not work correctly

Tags: joomla-2.5, sorting

I have custom component and in one of views column sorting does not work correctly. It's very weird for me. Always sort in ASC direction...
I'll introduce what I have.
Model `populateState()`

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
    // Load the filter state.
    $filters = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filters', 'filters', array(), 'ARRAY');
    $this->setState('filters', $filters);

    $conditions = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.conditions', 'conditions', array(), 'ARRAY');
    $this->setState('conditions', $conditions);

    // Load the parameters.
    $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_ritcatalogue');
    $this->setState('params', $params);

    // List state information.
    parent::populateState('n.node_id', 'desc');
}
```

as you can see by default it's sorting by column `n.node_id` in `DESC` direction. `getListQuery()` contains:

```
// Add the list ordering clause.
$orderCol = $this->state->get('list.ordering', 'n.node_id');
$orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction', 'DESC');
$query->order($db->escape($orderCol . ' ' . $orderDirn));
```

also in view

```
$listDirn = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));
$listOrder = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction'));

<input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $listOrder; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $listDirn; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved... It was my simple fault.

In view I had

```
$listDirn = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));
$listOrder = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction'));
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $listOrder; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $listDirn; ?>" />
```

instead of

```
$listDirn = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.direction'));
$listOrder = $this->escape($this->state->get('list.ordering'));
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $listOrder; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $listDirn; ?>" />
```

where direction was ordering column and column was direction (wrong parameters in get())

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
parent::populateState('n.node_id', 'desc');
}
```

**getlistquery:**

```
$orderCol = $this->state->get('list.ordering', 'n.node_id');
$orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction', 'desc');
```

**xml file:**

```
<field
      name="fullordering"
      type="list"
      label="Give label name"
      description="Give description name"
      onchange="this.form.submit();"
      default="n.node_id DESC"
   >
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: Now try it and check your backend

Comment: Thanks for your reply but same again... For me it's very weird because I have written a lot of views and only here is this problem

Comment: Please refer this site https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_sortable_columns_to_a_table_in_a_component you can find some solution.

Comment: I have already read this article. Joomla always sort in ASC direction when I click on column header. Moreover there is no "filter image" next to header

Comment: change the existing answer now try it and check your backend

Comment: Problem is just solved. There was another issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jextn - I've been looking through some of your answers recently. As much as everyone is appreciative, I would strongly suggest you try to add a little more detail to your answers. Saying "try this" and then providing code is fine, but let the OP know what the difference is between your and theirs. Maybe also try and explain what they're doing wrong ;)